# Extend the ubuntu root partition with unallocated space

Tags: partitioning, gparted

I don't seem to be able to figure out how to extend the disk space on Ubuntu 16.

Currently I'm stuck with this situation:

[image: GParted screenshot]

I want to extend the `/dev/sda6` with the unallocated memory above it which I just shrunk from Windows itself. I know this question has been asked multiple times but none seem to help me out. What's the smartest way to do this?

Another option is to just be able to use multiple partitions in Ubuntu, I don't know how.

Comment: I'm not able to "unmount" the /dev/sda6 btw.

Comment: To unmount, you have to use Ubuntu Live environment

Comment: can you be more specific?

Comment: Boot with Ubuntu Live DVD/USB, use Gparted from there.

Comment: Im now booted from the USB and was able to unmount the partition, but to extend the partition i need to move it because the unallocated memory is above it, this will cause the boot thingy to be moved too right? isnt this bad and how do i fix that?

Comment: Not sure really, need to check on Google

Comment: Have a look here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MovingLinuxPartition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer...

---

## First backup any important data from sda6!

Data loss or data corruption is possible.

---

- boot to the Ubuntu Live DVD/USB
- start `gparted`
- right-click on sda6 and select **move/resize**
- hover the cursor over sda6 and it'll turn into a hand
- **move** (drag) the entire sda6 partition all the way to the left
- hover the cursor over the right edge of sda6 and it'll turn into an arrow
- **resize** the partition all the way to the right
- click the `Apply` icon

Comment: If my answer was helpful, please **vote** by clicking the grey up-arrow icon in the upper-left of my answer, and **accept** my answer by clicking the grey checkmark icon in the upper-left of my answer. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but will it still be able to boot? as the boot location is being changed or will be changed

Comment: In my experience, Windows is the only OS that sometimes fails to boot after moving partitions. The sda6 move is fairly easy and straight-forward.

Comment: Now that the partition is bigger, use resize2fs to increase the size of the filesystem so you can use the space.

Comment: @ubfan1 resize2fs is not needed to resize sda6.